# How to find Average of multiple columns in a table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to find AVG of val1, val2, val3 and which will show in the Total column.

```
 service  val1  val2 val3   AVG
  A        0      3    5      ?
  B        3     8     9      ?
  C        2     0    10      ?
```

I want to find AVG of val1, val2, val3 and which will show in the AVG column.

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - if you have data of the same "kind" appearing in multiple columns, it's usually an indication that there should be a single column for that data, an additional column to contain the *data* that has become embedded in the column *names* (here, 1, 2 and 3) and then multiple *rows* instead. Then the SQL language has the tools to make these sorts of queries easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp (val1 int, val2 int, val3 int)

insert into #temp
values (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (1, 5, 19)


select (val1 +val2+val3)/3.00 as [AVG], *  from #temp group by val1, val2, val3
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this will perform integer math and so produce integer results, which may not be exactly what's wanted.

Comment: if there are null values  !!